# How to integrate a part of one html website into java program?

Tags: java, html, web-crawler

Given a HTML website which displays a temperature outside and other unimportant peaces of information:

```
<div style="">15</div>
```

15 - is my destination number, which I want to extract as a variable.

Now what I want to do is, that Java program will go to the website, search for the particular HTML  code line (temperature=15;) and after it is found, it must display it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY0qi.jpg

All I want to know, what syntax should I use to let program request that number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting information from a website is called *crawling* or *scraping*.

You basically go to the web site, get the HTML source and search it for your element. You can search with a regular expression or (more common) with a parser like **Jsoup**.

You will find a lot of working examples on the official site of Jsoup (e.g. http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links). Jsoup will parse the HTML source into a DOM-like structure with elements and nodes. You can search for specific nodes, e.g. for all DIV elements. Then you can iterate over them and get your temperature.

Answer (score 1):

There are tools called [scraper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) that extract information from the web .thare are many Java API that let  you write your own scraper. You can try with [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) ,[HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) or [Jaunt](http://jaunt-api.com/) .